# Recommended way to extend entities and configure foreign keys for dropdowns in abp-dynamic-form

Tags: abp

I am trying to learn abp module development. I have a problem that i couldn't resolve for days. Is there a smart way to populate foreignkey values to populate a dropdown in a abp-dynamic-form in a abp module template.

The point that I can't understand is, in abp module template, dtos are located in .contracts project. But contracts project doesn't have dependency on .domain project. Contracts project only has dependency for .domain.shared project. And domain.shared has no project dependency. So, for instance i have CityDto as :

```
public class CityDto : EntityDto<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country: : AggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

CityDto should include Country info. But Country is unkown for .contracts project. Because Country was defined in .domain project. Please would someone giving an example of code, that showing how to achieve this. I would like to construct an abp-dynamic-form that allows selecting country value in a dropdown, forexample while creating an City row in db. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your dto contains entity. One of the main point of dto is, exposing selective properties of entities instead of the whole entity.

So, your `CityDto` should contain `CountryDto` with the properties you decide to expose in your `Country` entity instead of the entity itself.

```
public class CityDto : EntityDto<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; } //This should also be CountryDto
}
```

Abp layered arhitecture prevents you using entities inside dtos with project dependencies.